# Error When Access Mutillidae with Xampp on Windows 11

Tags: security, xampp

I've already follows the step from website bellow:
https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/security/9781788624039/1/ch01lvl1sec03/installing-mutillidae-on-windows

But, Suddendly I found an error:
By default, Mutillidae II only allows access from non-routable network addresses. Edit the .htaccess file to change this behavior. Delete the .htaccess file if network access is controlled using a different method.

Can somebody tell me how to fix this error?

I already tried to search in the bing AI and severa website. But, I didn;t get any answer that I need to fix the error